# is it safe when using JSONObject.optString as JSON sanitizer?

Tags: javascript, json, eval, scriptengine

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
        ScriptEngineManager  manager =  new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("c:\\temp\\json.txt")));
        String xx= json.optString("xx");
        engine.eval("var yy = " + xx + ".yy;");
        Object output = engine.get("yy");
    }
```

json.txt like

```
{
  xx: {
    inject1: "(function(){java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)})()",
    yy: {
       inject1: "something injected"
    }
  }
}
```

optString will return double quotation mark string, so is it definitely safe for eval function?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: i tried, such as  \u2028 \u0022.   i can not find any word sucessed to inject. up to now it's safe. half in doubt